# How to get privileged (permissions) access for our app on Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, java

I'm a developer and new to Linux. I coded a Jframe Java program which performs File (create, delete, read, write, mkdir) operations. It works fine on windows, but not Linux.

My program does not have permission to read and write files or to create directories.

How do I give permissions to our own developed program on Linux?

Comment: sudo filename or sudo ./filename

Comment: Create files/directories _where_ exactly? Your app has the permissions of the user it's running as.

Comment: To the `sudo` enthusiasts: I wouldn't so easily suggest the `sudo` sledgehammer and let the program run with root permissions. If the program is faulty (as all newly written programs tend to be), then it can live up its faultiness with the full impact of root user's privileges. Bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

**Correct answer:** Linux permissions are not a binary on or off... I'd recommend starting by learning a bit about how they work. A good place to start would be [Introduction to linux permissions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-permissions). Once you have reviewed that, you'll know that the user running the application determines what permissions the application has. So if you want the application to have more permissions, you'll need to have it run by a user with those permissions.

**Short answer:** You can give the application root user permissions by calling `sudo application` so let's say you application was `notepad`, from a terminal window, you'd type `sudo notepad` and the application would have permissions to read/right files where ever root has permissions, which is pretty much everywhere.